# Running Php desktop application in client's pc

Tags: php, phpdesktop

I tried to make my php project to run as a desktop application using php desktop.But I want to make it more portable rather than installing mysql and apache server in client's pc.Is there any way to make it more portable?

Comment: Use SQLite database to make it portable.

Comment: You are the developer of it right.God never thought to talk with such a legend

Comment: Thank you. For more information see: https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop/wiki/Knowledge-Base#how-to-use-sqlite